# Android: .jar file in libs vs dependency url in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, jar, libs

I have come across two ways when I am adding jar dependency in an android project in Android Studio.

1. Adding *.jar file in libs folder.
2. Adding dependency url in gradle.build.

Which one is better and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I particularly prefer the dependency URL. A static library file in the project directory is seldom a better choice.

If a dependency is updated, you just have to update the `build.gradle`. No need of downloading and replacing files, which adds size to the project (kilo or megabytes in the file system). Also, manually updating these files is an error-prone action.

If the project is in a version control system (e.g. Git), commiting the jars to the repository is arguably a bad practice, whereas a modification in `build.gradle` is perfectly acceptable.

Another advantage of dependency declaration is smart dependency management. If an artifact in use depends on another one, the dependency management is done automatically by e.g. Gradle or Maven. If a statically added jar has a dependency, it has to be manually added to the project, which is a laborious, tedious, and error-prone task.

Comment: Is there any effect on apk size?

Comment: @AnujaKothekar no, not at all

Comment: I have observed when I kept *.jar in project for some functionality my apk size was 15mb and then I replaced with dependency it is now 11mb approx. Is this effect of gradle or just that whatever is downloaded from gradle is having smaller size?

Comment: @AnujaKothekar i edited the answer. Please look at the last paragraph. The size difference may be caused by the dependencies of dependencies, which are efficiently managed by Gradle